# GLMM or LME? Repeated measures help?

Tags: r, repeated-measures, glmm, lme4-nlme, ecology

I am having trouble using the correct test and r code for my experiment. Essentially I measured insect emergence daily from artificial streams with 3 treatments.:

```
CONTROL - With 5 replicate streams  
TREAT 1 - With 5 Replicate streams  
TREAT 2 - With 5 Rep streams.  
TREAT 2- With 5 rep streams
```

I think what I basically want to do is this: Emergence = Treatment + Day + Treatment*Day

Looking for an effect of treatment on insect emergence over time (day)

Update, I have just ran the model below, but it seems to be dropping a treatment group?

Ran this model:

```
> model6 <- lmer(Emerg ~ Day + Treatment + Day:Treatment + (Day | Stream), insect)
> summary(model6)

Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: 
Emerg ~ Day + Treatment + Day:Treatment + (Day | Stream)
   Data: insect

REML criterion at convergence: 2070.8

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.0321 -0.4694 -0.0445  0.3883  4.8618 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance  Std.Dev. Corr
 Stream   (Intercept) 672.73598 25.9372      
          Day           0.01573  0.1254  1.00
 Residual             594.41059 24.3805      
Number of obs: 224, groups:  Stream, 16

Fixed effects:
                        Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)              68.7060    14.6813   4.680
Day                      -0.7632     0.8106  -0.941
TreatmentControl        -26.5467    20.7625  -1.279
TreatmentFluoxetine     -14.0357    20.7625  -0.676
TreatmentMix            -15.0879    20.7625  -0.727
Day:TreatmentControl      0.6181     1.1464   0.539
Day:TreatmentFluoxetine   1.5500     1.1464   1.352
Day:TreatmentMix          1.3808     1.1464   1.204

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) Day    TrtmnC TrtmnF TrtmnM Dy:TrC Dy:TrF
Day         -0.343                                          
TrtmntCntrl -0.707  0.243                                   
TrtmntFlxtn -0.707  0.243  0.500                            
TreatmentMx -0.707  0.243  0.500  0.500                     
Dy:TrtmntCn  0.243 -0.707 -0.343 -0.172 -0.172              
Dy:TrtmntFl  0.243 -0.707 -0.172 -0.343 -0.172  0.500       
Dy:TrtmntMx  0.243 -0.707 -0.172 -0.172 -0.343  0.500  0.500
>
```

Comment: what is emergence?

Comment: Insect emergence- emergence of the flying adult from the stream channel

Comment: so it is a continuous measure?

Comment: I don't see where the repeated measures comes in.  You are using the same insects for each treatment?

Comment: also what are streams?

Comment: Insects are measured daily and collected, day is the repeated measure

Answer (score 1):

If you measured emergence as a continuous measure I would start with a mixed-effects model, but if the measure is dichotomous (e.g., yes or no) then generalized LMM is the way to start.

I will assume your response variable is continuous. I would use the `lmer()` function from the `lme4` package in `R`. Your base model could look something like this:

```
Model <- lmer(Emergence ~ Treat + Day + Treat*Day + (1|Stream_id), data = Data_Frame)   
summary(Model)
```

You have to tell the model that individual streams have multiple measures by treating it as a random factor (i.e, `(1|Stream_id)`). The `1|...` indicates the model will include a random intercept for individual streams. It looks like you are trying to include a random intercept and slope for the random effect `Stream`, as a function of the effect of `Day`, which you would code as `(1+Day|Stream)` in package `lem4`.

The reason you are missing a treatment is because it is incorporated into the `(Intercept)`. All of your visible treatments are being compared to the "missing" treatment in the intercept. So, your output does not compare the effect of `TreatmentControl` and the effect of `TreatmentFluoxetine`, and so on

I think you are interested in the interaction between `Day` and `Treatment`. That is, does the effect of `Day` on `Emergence` change depending on the type of `Treatment` used. If so, a simpler approach may be to use the repeated measures of `Day` to calculate one response variable, such as rate of emergence or total emergence. Then, a simple anova will tell you if the `Treatment` type affects the rate of emergence, total emergence, or what have you.

Hope this helps you get started. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! My measure of emergence is contentious. Is a mixed effect model the correct way to go, or should it simply be a repeated measures? With day being the repeated measure? Also when I run the model, it seems to drop one of my treatment from the comparisons?

Comment: Your measure of emergence is likely to inspire debate?